# Binding Controls to a Settings File

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, settings

I want to be able to control several groups of settings independently of each other. I'd originally used My.Settings, but it was too much work to manually rollback some settings whilst saving others.

I thought my solution was to use multiple settings files, and I've had moments where this seemed to work, but I whatever success I have had is periodic and temporary.

Currently I have two settings files in the root of the project; In code, I can access the settings OK, but in many cases I want to bind individual settings to controls. This *should* be straight-forward, and I recall it working when I used the single, built-in settings file.

However, when I use the two new settings files it doesn't work. In the *Formatting & Advanced Binding* dialog, I select *Add New Project Data Source*, I browse into my project, then into the root namespace, and then I see my forms/classes/settings files. When I select the two settings files, and click OK, the dialog is dismissed without me being able to select an individual setting to bind the control to.

When I enable *Project > Show All Files*, I can see that the binding has been created; I have two *.datasource* files under *My Project > Datasources*.

Is there some reason why I shouldn't be able to bind to these settings files? If not, why can I not access them the the data-binding dialogs?

Plan B is to create an object to act as an intermediary between the controls and the settings files, but I'd rather avoid this if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had no problems databinding to the settings file or to a custom settings file that I added with a property called "other":

```
Public Sub New()
  InitializeComponent()

  TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", My.Settings, "Test")
  TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", custom.Default, "other")
End Sub
```

The only "hitch" I found with the custom settings file was it wouldn't write to the settings file automatically the way the default `My.Settings` did.  I added this to my form:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnFormClosing(ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs)
  custom.Default.Save()

  MyBase.OnFormClosing(e)
End Sub
```

Then the settings persisted.

Comment: TBH, I hadn't tried binding in code - I just assumed to wouldn't work, if binding through the designer didn't. However it does work - it's a little more typing, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Also, I *think* it behaves the same as for My.Settings. Regardless, you can control this through the binding declaration: 

`TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", custom.Default, "other", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)` - but I wanted to manually control changes so I was using the OnFormClosing event

Comment: @CJM I played around with a lot of those settings, I just couldn't get the `custom.Default` to save the next time I started the program.  Hence the `OnFormClosing()` save call to persist the setting.  On the first comment, I find the designer gets in the way more than it helps, so I always try to do things in code where I have more "control" of things.

Comment: Did you explicitly set the update mode? I *think* it defaults to OnValidation. I don't need the automatic updates as I said, but as a courtesy to you, I tried it. For me, setting the updated mode to OnPropertyChanged, *DID* work.

Comment: @CJM No difference.  The binding works during the life of the application, but when I restart the program, the initial variable is not the way I last left it unless I call `Save()` on that settings file.